# AngularJS stopped...working? When published only. Nothing changed

Tags: angularjs

I rolled back all changes to my entire web project. Zero changes whatsoever. Yesterday when I published to my dev environment (Azure) everything worked as expected. Today when I publish to my dev environment (same publish profile, literally zero changes to the entire project I"m publishing) I get these weird errors...

1. Unexpected end of input on angular.js:1
2. This of course cascades down to every controller/service saying angular is undefined

If I switch my script tag to use angular.min.js it works again. I suspect if I replace the file it'll also work again, but I don't understand why or what happened. Could this be indicative of some other issue?

**Update 1**

I tried upgrading to latest Angular (replacing the angular.js file) and see the same behavior. It only "fixes" itself if I switch to using angular.min.js instead.

---

And here's my web.config for reference...

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->

<configuration>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <!--add json mime time-->
    <staticContent>
      <mimeMap fileExtension=".json" mimeType="application/json" />
    </staticContent>

    <!--https redirect-->
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Force HTTPS" enabled="true">
          <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>

  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

Comment: probably you are missing some configuration url/parameter to put inside your `web.config` which is using while making ajax..which is causing your page to stop loading

Comment: @pankajparkar I recently added an https redirect in my web.config but it worked last publish. zero changes since then. What specifically do you think it could be? (added my web.config to the question)

Comment: A couple of things 1)Are you doing any minification as part of your build process?  If so, are all you DI element declared in a Min-safe manner. 2) are you altering the references to angular.js vs angualr.min.js in all your pages as your flip back and forth between the two?

Comment: @JerryKur No, no automated minification (I do it all manually when deploying to production). This issue is presenting when I'm deploying to a shared dev enviro and there is no automation attached to the build/deploy process. [for what it's worth, everything is declared in a min-safe manner]

Comment: @JoshuaOhana that means with unminified angular.js it is working without error?

Comment: @JoshuaOhana Here are few more question what are the error in console? which version of angular you are using.? is angular.min.map file is included?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so as mysteriously as this issue appeared, it apparently fixed itself? I'll leave this here incase anyone else encounters the same problem.

I kept changing back and forth between importing angular.js and angular.min.js, and published a dozen or so times... 'lo and behold one time it worked! And seems to continue to. I don't think this has anything to do with cache as I constantly clear it. Oh well...

Comment: Where you checking these into source control system.  It would be interesting to see.  BTW, the comment about caching may be key.  I tell my browsers to never cache anything on my development systems.  Caching is evil for web developers.